# Rename tag macosx to mac-os-x

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

May we please rename [macosx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macosx) to [mac-os-x](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x)?

At first glance I thought the first form read *macros*.  I believe the hyphenated form is more readable.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I agree to a renaming, but I think it should simply be [tag:osx] for two reasons: 1) It maintains uniformity across all SE sites (SO, SU AskDifferent, Unix, AskUbuntu all have `osx`), so it'll be easy for someone to use an SE wide filter. 2) [tag:osx] is fairly obvious, so the mac prefix is redundant. Those who don't know probably won't care.

Answer (score 2):

Done (and I went ahead with R.M's idea and used [osx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) as the main tag), but you could have done it yourself from the mod panel, y'know... ;)

Comment: I was trying to get community support first.  Further, as shown above, someone might have a better suggestion.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think that some decisions are rather "soft" and you could probably go ahead with a straw poll in chat or do it yourself, if it is straightforward — after all, mods were chosen to do stuff on the community's behalf. In any case, this is a reversible decision, so no major harm done. Merges, on the other hand, are messy and irreversible (unless a dev intervenes). If we decide to put each and every tag renaming decision through the community vote wringer, it'll be a bureaucratic nightmare. I'm fine with either approach though.